# Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-11.There are no JRE's installed in the workplace that are strictly with this environment spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Installed JDK 1.8 and Spring boot suite. When I created my first project in spring boot, I got warning -Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-11.There are no JRE's installed in the workplace that are strictly with this environment?
I checked preference->java-> Installed JRE's->selected 1.8 JRE-added it and then selected JVM and selected JRE folder as JDK 1.8 folder and new name for JRE.But still the warning shows

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the version in your pom.xml file. If it matches with 1.8 too and still the error shows up, then right click on your project and try maven->update. There must be some kind of option to refresh the project and refresh those dependencies.

Comment: maven->update project most likely, Spring Tool Suite seems to be based on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check jdk in run configuration. Also have a look in the project properties -> java compiler, and java libraries for the application.